# Javascript - Add to Table Form html code if something selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this table, where are placed product selector:

```
<table border="1px" class="multi">
<tr><td>

            <label for="productSelect">Produkts:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
<select id="productSelect" onchange="myFunction()" name="product" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected">-Produkts-</option>
    <option value="430">OCTA</option>
    <option value="440">KASKO</option>
    <option value="19041">TRAVEL</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
<div id="product-info">
<!-- HTML JS CODE WILL BE THERE -->
</div>
</table>
```

I'm trying with JS code add rows to this table, but it works not correctly, and add only input field, without table at the top of my table with product field.

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("productSelect").value;
    if(x == 430 | x == 440) {
        var html ='<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td></tr>';
    }
    if(x == 19041){
        var html = 'You selected: ' + x;
    }
    if(x == ''){
        var html = '<b>You need to select Product!</b>';
    }
    document.getElementById("product-info").innerHTML = html;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/aa7qfn6p/

i replaced

```
function myFunction() {
```

by

```
myFunction = function() {
```

and it worked

By the way, you can't put your div between /tr and /table
JSFIDDLE UPDATED => https://jsfiddle.net/aa7qfn6p/1/

Comment: it's don't work, I need that table rows adds after Product choose. But it adds before.

Comment: </td></tr>
</table><div id="product-info">
<!-- HTML JS CODE WILL BE THERE -->
</div>

Comment: and create another table with js like: var html ='<table border="1px"><tr><td></td><td><input type="text" name="quantity" value='+x+' /></td></tr></table>'; ?

Comment: you can add a table in the div if the div is outside the /tr and /table

Comment: if you want it in the same table, you can do this : https://jsfiddle.net/aa7qfn6p/2/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to achieve?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("productSelect").value;
  if (x == 430 | x == 440) {
    var html = '<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td></tr>';
  }
  if (x == 19041) {
    var html = 'You selected: ' + x;
  }
  if (x == '') {
    var html = '<b>You need to select Product!</b>';
  }
  document.getElementById("product-info").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px" class="multi">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="productSelect">Produkts:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="productSelect" onchange="myFunction()" name="product" required>
        <option value="" selected="selected">-Produkts-</option>
        <option value="430">OCTA</option>
        <option value="440">KASKO</option>
        <option value="19041">TRAVEL</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="product-info">
        <!-- HTML JS CODE WILL BE THERE -->
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```